# Bug in close question modal as duplicate - input field left filled and close button disabled

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, user-experience

I got confused while closing a question, and I found this *possible* bug in the question close modal. Here's how to reproduce it (modal):

1. Choose *duplicate of*, then I input a link.
2. Go back to the initial menu--click on *"closing"* not "back to similar questions", and then choose *duplicate of* again.
3. The link field is filled with the previous link. Yet, the button is disabled.

[image: Screenshot]

Only a change in the field will re-enable the button. I believe that the field should be either reset or the button shall be enabled such event--when there is a link chosen earlier. This sequence I followed could be very rare, but I suspect that this is mostly by design for the user to re-consider the link.

Comment: I'm certain this has been reported before, but I'm not finding it with a quick search. I'm probably not getting the keywords right. Also a good chance it is on the global Meta instead of here.

Comment: @CodyGray, why didn't they fix it then?

Comment: How should I know?

Comment: @AdamAzad- It might have been fixed at one point, bugs creep back up you know when functionality changes...It happens to the best of us!